# Picklist values in a formula on a validation rule (along with text fields)

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist, validation-rule

I have a validation rule on the contract object which doesn't allow a checkbox to be checked by users until they have completed the required fields. The issue is that some of these fields are picklist values and are very much needed. 
Here is the rule with the other fields (without the picklist ones):

```
AND( 
OR( 
ISBLANK (Knowledge__c ), 
ISBLANK(Functional_Skills__c), 
ISBLANK(App_Attendance_Absent__c), 
ISBLANK(App_Attendance_Late__c), 
ISBLANK(App_Attendance_Present__c), 
ISBLANK(App_Attendance_Present_including_Late2__c), 
ISBLANK(How_can_you_improve_your_score__c), 
ISBLANK(Apprentice__c), 
ISBLANK(Career_Options__c), 
ISBLANK(Competency__c), 
ISBLANK(Date_of_last_Review__c), 
ISBLANK(Date_of_this_review__c ), 
ISBLANK(Due_Date_1__c), 
ISBLANK(Due_Date_2__c), 
ISBLANK(Due_Date_3__c), 
ISBLANK(Employer_Representative_Comments__c), 
ISBLANK(English_Diagnostic_Assessment__c), 
ISBLANK(Functional_Skills__c), 
ISBLANK(Health_Safety_E_D_topic__c), 
ISBLANK(How_would_you_score_yourself__c), 
ISBLANK(Issues_or_Concerns__c), 
ISBLANK(LDS_Comments__c), 
ISBLANK(LDS_How_to_improve_score_next_month__c), 
ISBLANK(maths_English__c), 
ISBLANK(maths_Diagnostic_Assessment__c), 
ISBLANK(Overall_Progress_Blue__c), 
ISBLANK(Overall_Progress_Green__c), 
ISBLANK(Overall_Progress_Orange__c), 
ISBLANK(PDP__c), 
ISBLANK(Projects_or_areas_of_work__c), 
ISBLANK(Review_Location__c), 
ISBLANK(Safeguarding_topic__c), 
ISBLANK(Score_for_the_month__c), 
ISBLANK(LDS_Score_for_the_month__c), 
ISBLANK(Target_1__c), 
ISBLANK(Target_2__c), 
ISBLANK(Target_3__c), 
ISBLANK(To_keep_myself_and_others_safe_I_can__c), 
ISBLANK(Work_Attendance_Late__c), 
ISBLANK(Work_Attendance_Sick__c) 
), 
Review_Completed__c = true 
)
```

Here are the picklist value fields:

```
       ISBLANK(All_Smart_Targets_met__c),
   ISBLANK(Additional_Support__c),
   ISBLANK(Apprentice_of_the_month__c),
   ISBLANK(Apprenticeship_work__c),
   ISBLANK(At_risk_record_to_be_created_or_updated__c),
   ISBLANK(Do_we_need_to_open_FS_aims__c),
   ISBLANK(Enrichment_sessions__c),
   ISBLANK(For_Whom__c),
   ISBLANK(For_Whom_2__c),
   ISBLANK(For_Whom_3__c),
   ISBLANK(Is_employer_partnerships_input_required__c),
   ISBLANK(Is_the_manager_happy_generally__c),
   ISBLANK(Qualification_Level__c),
   ISBLANK(Reflective_log__c),
   ISBLANK(Target_Type_1__c),
   ISBLANK(Target_Type_2__c),
   ISBLANK(Target_Type_3__c),
   ISBLANK(The_Employer_Reference__c),
   ISBLANK(Upcoming__c),
```

Thaanks :)

Comment: whats the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a picklist is blank with the following `ISBLANK(Text(picklist__c))`

Therefore you need:

```
ISBLANK(TEXT(All_Smart_Targets_met__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Additional_Support__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Apprentice_of_the_month__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Apprenticeship_work__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(At_risk_record_to_be_created_or_updated__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Do_we_need_to_open_FS_aims__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Enrichment_sessions__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(For_Whom__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(For_Whom_2__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(For_Whom_3__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Is_employer_partnerships_input_required__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Is_the_manager_happy_generally__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Qualification_Level__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Reflective_log__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Target_Type_1__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Target_Type_2__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Target_Type_3__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(The_Employer_Reference__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Upcoming__c)),
```